# Draw Circle inside row in Flutter using Paint

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to achieve this

[image]

notice the circle in right bottom.

right now with I have reached this

[image]

with the following code

```
Container(
                            width: 113.w,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                CustomPaint(
                                  foregroundPainter:
                                      CircleProgress(done: 3, total: 4),
                                  size: Size(20, 20),
                                  // child: Center(child: Text("3/4")),
                                ),
                                Text("Weeks"),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
```

Custom Paint

```
class CircleProgress extends CustomPainter {
  int done;
  int total;

  CircleProgress({required this.total, required this.done});

  final strokeWidth = 8.0;
  @override
 void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
Paint totalCircle = Paint()
  ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
  ..color = const Color(0xFF8989BE)
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

Paint doneCircle = Paint()
  ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
  ..color = const Color(0xFFDFDFFD).withOpacity(0.96)
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

Offset center = Offset(100.w, 35.h);
double radius = 25.r;
double angle = 2 * pi * (done / total);

canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, totalCircle);

canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius), pi / 2,
    angle, false, doneCircle);
 }
```

how can I put the painted circle and weeks text in the place I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `CustomPaint` into a `Stack` ... now you are able to place the 3/4 Text Widget inside of the CustumPaint

more about the stack widget:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Set your CustomPaint Widget Size to the correct Size. And double Check your initial offset. For your circle.

example...    if the circle's radius is 50 your CustomPaint Size should be (100,100)   ... but don't forget the pixels of the borderWidth

the circle offset shoult be 50,50 too

here an example:

```
Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 113,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  CustomPaint(
                    foregroundPainter: CircleProgress(done: 3, total: 4),
                    size: Size(58, 58),
                    // child: Center(child: Text("3/4")),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Text("Weeks"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

circle class:

```
class CircleProgress extends CustomPainter {
  int done;
  int total;

  CircleProgress({required this.total, required this.done});

  final strokeWidth = 8.0;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint totalCircle = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..color = const Color(0xFF8989BE)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    Paint doneCircle = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..color = const Color(0xFFDFDFFD).withOpacity(0.96)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    Offset center = Offset(29, 29);
    double radius = 25;
    double angle = 2 * pi * (done / total);

    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, totalCircle);

    canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius), pi / 2, angle, false, doneCircle);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not the problem.
my problem is to how to put the Painted circle and "Weeks" in correct order after each other.

Comment: ah ok... the problem here is your defined size for your customPaint widget

Comment: take a look in my edited answer... should help ;-)   let a upvote here if its fine :-D